# Footer on a multi horizontal-div website

Tags: html, css

I wasn't really sure how to put divs beside each other. I found a solution here, however, instead of subsequent text going below (where it should) the text now aligns to the right. This wouldn't normally be a problem because all of the content is inside the main container, however, I want my footer to appear at the bottom of the page.

Here is the website: http://www.winterlb.com/test/

The "test" at the right is what I want to appear at the bottom of the page, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` above your footer div

Comment: Better practice would just be to add the style `clear: both;` to the footer div itself; no need for the extra markup.